# Disable Ctrl-A (Cmd-A) text selection in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, selection

In this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jUfe4/3/) you can not select in Firefox the text using the mouse. But this is still possible using the Cmd-A or Ctrl-A key sequence. Is there a way to disable this in Firefox?

I am using this CSS class:

```
.noselect {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

I am trying to do this NOT to block text copying, but to only to let Ctrl-A + Ctrl-C work on certain elements to enhance the user experience. Like, you land on a page, copy it and paste it into Excel. Only the useful information should land in Excel (no copyrights, logout links, menus, etc.).

Comment: I hope you're not trying to prevent copying of the text, because that's futile either way.

Comment: Nope, only selection. It is only a visual thing. I have edited the question for this and added this remark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google is your friend.

```js
/***********************************************
* Disable Text Selection script- © Dynamic Drive DHTML code library (www.dynamicdrive.com)
* This notice MUST stay intact for legal use
* Visit Dynamic Drive at http://www.dynamicdrive.com/ for full source code
***********************************************/

function disableSelection(target) {
  if (typeof target.onselectstart != "undefined") //IE route
    target.onselectstart = function() { return false; }
  else if (typeof target.style.MozUserSelect != "undefined") //Firefox route
    target.style.MozUserSelect = "none"
  else //All other route (ie: Opera)
    target.onmousedown = function() { return false; }
  target.style.cursor = "default";
}

//Sample usages
//disableSelection(document.body) //Disable text selection on entire body
//disableSelection(document.getElementById("mydiv")) //Disable text selection on element with id="mydiv"
```

Fixed the code above: http://jsfiddle.net/jUfe4/7/

```
function disableSelection(target) {
    var ieSelect = typeof target.onselectstart != "undefined";
    var ffSelect = typeof target.style.MozUserSelect != "undefined"

    if (ieSelect) target.onselectstart = function () { return false; };
    else if (ffSelect) target.style.MozUserSelect = "none"
    else target.onmousedown = function () { return false; };

    target.style.cursor = "default";
}
```

- http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex9/noselect.htm
- http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?191294-Disable-ctrl-a-in-Firefox

Comment: See the edited question (at the end). This looks like a very costly option (performance) for an "inclusion-based element selection" (i.e. disable selection everywhere but enable it on certain elements only). Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in Firefox it is only a **visual** thing (bug). The text gets selected when pressing Ctrl-A, but it is **NOT** copied when pressing Ctrl-C.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var isCtrl = false,
    isCmd  = false;

$(document).keyup(function (e) {

 if(e.ctrlKey)
     isCtrl=false;
     isCmd  = false;

}).keydown(function (e) {
    if(e.ctrlKey) 
        isCtrl = true;
        isCmd = true;

    if(e.which == 65 && isCtrl == true) {
        console.log('ctrl+a');    
        return false;
    }

    if(e.which == 65 && isCmd == true) {
        console.log('cmd+a');    
        return false;
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9ytfe/13/

Comment: Probably a combination: http://jsfiddle.net/9ytfe/14/ But still not complete. In firefox you can right-click -> Select All or double click. These will still select the text. So probably a solution closer to the one using `onselectstart` would be better.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){   
    $(document).keydown(function(objEvent) {        
        if (objEvent.ctrlKey) {          
            if (objEvent.keyCode == 65) {                         
                objEvent.disableTextSelect();
                return false;
            }            
        }        
    });
});
```

65 is the ASCII code of 'A', add 97 if you want to check also for 'a'.

You can do it with CSS:

```
div {
    user-select:none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
}
```

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/user-select)